# Request URL on Meteor server

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to know from which URL the request is coming on on Meteor server?

Specifically, i would like to filter `Meteor.publish` method based on the URL params the request has. Doing this on server would be more secure than sending the params from client in `Meteor.subscribe`, since client side vars can be hacked.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that at least inside `Meteor.publish` function you can find request URL from `this.session.socket.headers`.